# Error in Float can't be interpreted as an integer in old code

Tags: python

I am trying to reuse this old function generated by a former employee and the company I now work at and am receiving the error "TypeError: object of type <class 'float'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer."
I thought I could fix it quite easily with integer division // but that doesn't seem to be fixing the issue.

```
def ricker(f, length, dt): # function for Ricker wavelet
    t = np.linspace(-length / 2, (length-dt) / 2, length / dt)
    y = (1. - 2.*(np.pi**2)*(f**2)*(t**2))*np.exp(-(np.pi**2)*(f**2)*(t**2))
    return t, y

def synthy(rho,v,f,dt,v_scale,h_scale):
    Z = rho*v 
    scaled_dt = v_scale * 1.0/v[:,0] 
    tdr = 2 * np.cumsum(scaled_dt)
    t = np.arange(tdr.min(), tdr.max(), dt)
    tw, w = ricker (f=f, length = 0.99*len(t)*dt, dt = dt)
    
    Stemp = [] 
    lengths = [] 
    
   
    for i in range(rho.shape[1]):
        scaled_dt = v_scale * 1.0/v[:,i] 
        tdr = 2 * np.cumsum(scaled_dt) 
        t = np.arange(tdr.min(), tdr.max(), dt)
        Z_t = np.interp(x = t, xp = tdr, fp = Z[:,i])
        RC_t = (Z_t[1:] - Z_t[:-1]) / (Z_t[1:] + Z_t[:-1]) 
        synth = np.convolve(RC_t, w, mode='same') 
        Stemp.append(synth)
        lengths.append(len(synth))
        
    S = np.zeros((min(lengths),rho.shape[1]))
    for i in range(rho.shape[1]):
        S[:,i] = Stemp[i][:min(lengths)]

    
    return S, fig, w, tw

S, fig, w, tw = synthy(rho,v,f=100,dt=0.0001,v_scale=v_scale,h_scale=h_scale)
```

Comment: I don't understand why people will post a 100-line program with an error, and not tell is WHICH LINE HAD THE ERROR...

Comment: @ Tim Roberts - you're right my mistake on that. From what I can tell my errors are coming in at lines 32 and 41

Comment: This is a code dump. I looked through your code I can't figure out the line which has error. Narrow down stuff and just tell exactly which line has error. However for your error, `int(float_value)` will do the conversion from float to int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

numpy.linspace requires an integer for its third parameter:

```
    t = np.linspace(-length / 2, (length-dt) / 2, int(length / dt))
```

Comment: Tim, you nailed it! I do apologize for the code dump y'all, still learning here and I will make sure future questions are more clear!

Comment: It's great that you included the code.  It's even better if I can RUN the code, but I was missing `rho` and `v`, and couldn't guess the values.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to convert any float into int using

```
print(int(floatValue))
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Comment: My fault. I assumed he knew where he had to convert it to integer. He had not posted his code since then and I was waiting for him to update it to provide a more relatable answer. But from what information I had, this was the correct answer. The other answer has also done this, just on a specific line since it knew the whole code